# Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, maven, redis

I have a Spring Boot (version 2.7.0) project with JDK17.
During build, Maven cannot resolve this dependency:

`org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:2.7.0`

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testingd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testingd</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is a screenshot illustrating the issue in my IDE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YTnG.png)

Comment: I add redis dependency, this error show up. I dont know how can ı solve this

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new app with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and [Spring Data Redis (SDR) 2.7.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.7.0/reference/html/) and it builds with no problems using `./mvnw clean verify`.

Use Spring Initializr with [these settings](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-redis,web,devtools) to replicate.

Maybe you happen to catch an intermediate state when that JAR dependencies wasn't yet propagated in Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove version and let maven choose right version to you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If this does not work then add jedis depedency without version.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

worked like a charm for me.